# xmllint fails to validate XHTML 1.0 Transitional file

Tags: linux, validation, xhtml, xmllint, xhtml-transitional

Steps to reproduce on Debian Jessie GNU/Linux.

Check `xmllint` version:

```
$ xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20901
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib Lzma
```

Make an XHTML 1.0 Transitional file by saving this as `example.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>A title</title>
</head>

<body>
Some content
</body>

</html>
```

N.B. Pasting the contents of example.xhtml into the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/check) yields "This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!", so it should also validate when using `xmllint`.

### xmllint online validation

This fails, despite the fact that the computer has internet access:

```
$ xmllint --noout --valid example.xhtml
example.xhtml:1: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
                                                                               ^
example.xhtml:2: validity error : Validation failed: no DTD found !
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
                                                                  ^
```

### xmllint offline validation

Install [XHTML 1.0 DTDs and entity files](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html):

```
$ wget -qO- https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/xhtml1.tgz | tar xvz
xhtml1-20020801/
xhtml1-20020801/W3C-REC.css
xhtml1-20020801/xhtml.css
xhtml1-20020801/logo-REC.png
xhtml1-20020801/w3c_home.png
xhtml1-20020801/wcag1AAA.png
xhtml1-20020801/acks.html
xhtml1-20020801/Cover.html
xhtml1-20020801/definitions.html
xhtml1-20020801/diffs.html
xhtml1-20020801/dtds.html
xhtml1-20020801/guidelines.html
xhtml1-20020801/introduction.html
xhtml1-20020801/issues.html
xhtml1-20020801/normative.html
xhtml1-20020801/Overview.html
xhtml1-20020801/prohibitions.html
xhtml1-20020801/references.html
xhtml1-20020801/xhtml1-diff.html
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml-lat1.ent
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml-special.ent
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml-symbol.ent
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml.soc
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml1.dcl
xhtml1-20020801/xhtml1.ps
xhtml1-20020801/xhtml1.pdf
```

Still fails:

```
$ xmllint --noout --dtdvalid xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd example.xhtml 
example.xhtml:1: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
                                                                               ^
```

Likewise if using the `--nonet` option:

```
$ xmllint --noout --nonet --dtdvalid xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd example.xhtml 
I/O error : Attempt to load network entity http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd
example.xhtml:1: warning: failed to load external entity "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
                                                                               ^
```

### Questions

I have two questions:

1. Why did none of these validation attempts succeed?
2. The second one seems to fail because despite using the `--dtdvalid` option, `xmllint` still tries to visit `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd` because it is referenced in `example.xhtml`. Is there some way to tell `xmllint` to ignore that reference and to instead use a local DTD (e.g. the one already stored at `xhtml1-20020801/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the simplest workaround is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install w3c-dtd-xhtml
```

This installs the relevant DTDs locally. Thereafter, validation succeeds:

```
$ xmllint --noout --valid example.xhtml
$
```

However, although this allows me to validate the XHTML file, it does not really answer the questions. Therefore, I will not mark this question as "answered", in the hope that someone will provide an answer that does indeed answer them.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xmllint, so I'm not going to post a full answer, but apparently xmllint can only honour the `--nonet` option if there is indeed a DTD available locally. See also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/asciidoc/FC-eOwU8rYg).

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you get an error even if you do allow xmllint to go out and fetch the DTD from the net though. Are you sure xmllint can access the net? You don't have some kind of firewall that restricts access or something?

Comment: @MrLister, thanks. *"[Apparently] xmllint can only honour the `--nonet` option if there is indeed a DTD available locally."* Indeed. As you will see from the example in which I used `--nonet`, I specified a local DTD using `--dtdvalid`. *"Are you sure xmllint can access the net?"* I haven't set or detected any impediment to xmllint accessing the Internet. As you can see in my examples, wget works fine in the same environment (and I can confirm that it has not needed to be whitelisted, etc).